# Remove particular data from TableView w/o any button?

Tags: java, arraylist, javafx, tableview, observablelist

I've been doing Socket Programming for a while for my Major Project. So after reading alot from here and other blogs, I manage to make a TableView. But the problem is I'm not much familiar with TableView's api's, so this is a bit of problem for me.

```
public class Server implements Runnable {

    ServerSocket sersock;
    Socket sock;

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            sersock = new ServerSocket(9000);
            while (true) {
                sock = sersock.accept();
                new Thread(new client_handler(sock)).start();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

 public class client_handler implements Runnable { //Inner class.

        Socket sock;
        DataInputStream dis;
        DataOutputStream dos;
        String ip;

        public client_handler(Socket sock) {
            this.sock = sock;
        }

        public client_handler(String ip) {
            this.ip = ip;
        }

        public String getIp() {
            return ip;
        }

        public void setIp(String ip) {
            this.ip = ip;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                dis = new DataInputStream(sock.getInputStream());
                dos = new DataOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());

                ip = sock.getInetAddress().getHostAddress();
                System.out.println(ip);

                al.add(this);

                data.add(this);
            } catch (Exception e) {

                data.remove(this);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the part of initialization

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    // TODO
    iptracker.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("ip"));
    data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    tableView.setItems(data);
}
```

And here is my Declaration

```
@FXML
private TableView<Server.client_handler> tableView;
@FXML
private TableColumn iptracker;

ObservableList<Server.client_handler> data;
```

Now what I want is that, If the connection is established (of course it will), 
`client_handler` will be called with `sock` as parameter. Now I want to add this sock to my TableView as IP Address. But I don't know how to.?
Moreover, how can I delete `this` object when the connection dropped from other side in `catch(Exception e)` statement like I tried to do but no luck.!
Later I want to send the entire list via stream to other client. So how can I traverse every row of my TableView which obviously have only 1 column.
 I hope its not ill posted this time. :p
*I know ObservableList<> is different from ArrayList, but this project, I'm trying to port it from Swings, so jTable works great with ArrayList.*

Comment: To me, it makes more sense to declare your `cellFactory` as `iptracker.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("ip"));`

Comment: @ItachiUchiha , so you mean that i should insert getter and setter for for `ip` too??
But `client_handler` is called with `sock` as parameter?

Comment: It doesn't matter what client_handler is passed with as a parameter. We need to show the IP as a string, so we need a StringProperty in client_handler, which when updated should be shown in the table. If you ask me your project setup looks a little messed up.

Comment: @ItachiUchiha This is what I did, it its not wrong:
`ip = sock.getInetAddress().getHostAddress();
         new Thread(new client_handler(ip)).start();`
I extracted the IP from sock, and pass it to `client_handler`. The IP does shows up.
But now, I want to remove this same IP when my connection get dropped. I've tried `data.remove(ip);` but its not updating the table.

Edit: Oh, and I have added the `ip` to the table with `data.add(new client_handler(ip));`, and that too from inside client_handler. This thing looks me little weird.

Comment: I think using a StringProperty for ip and then just resetting it to an empty string `""` should work for you.

Comment: @ItachiUchiha, I've tried some hooks now. All seems to work fine, but now the problem is that `catch (Exception e)` is not working.?

Comment: Since you are presumably executing the client handler's `run()` method in a background thread, you need to wrap the changes to the data list (`data.add(this);` and `data.remove(this)`) in `Platform.runLater(...)`, so that you don't try to modify the table on a background thread.

Comment: @James_D, Can u elaborate it somehow. I couldn't get it clearly.

Comment: I don't know how else to say it. The calls that result in a modification to the table must be performed on the FX Application Thread. You can achieve that by wrapping them in a call to [`Platform.runLater(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater-java.lang.Runnable-).

Comment: @James_D searched bout it, I think its not the thing I'm looking. The problem was much complex for me. I tried some other solutions and the table working correctly (adding ip to it). But what I was quoting above was that, when the connection from client is dropped down, `catch` block should execute, resulting in `data.remove(this);`, but its not happening. The code `data.remove(this);` is working for sure, but not in `catch()` statement. THIS IS THE REAL PROBLEM NOW.

Comment: You haven't really shown enough relevant code, to diagnose your problem. However, it is well documented (e.g. see the "threading" section of the [`Application` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html)) that you cannot update the UI from a background thread. You need to fix that problem, aside from any other problems.

Comment: @James_D I'll take a look now. Will edit the OP then. But till then, can u tell me, why isn't catch block working?

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not working"? Is execution getting to that point (i.e. is an exception actually being thrown)? Is the code inside the catch block throwing an exception itself? What is actually happening?

Comment: @James_D https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9747708/Images/no_exception_occuring.JPG
As u can see, `catch(Exception e)` block needs to run, whenever the connection from client side is dropped. But in my case, no exception is coming.Not even the `System.out.printlin()` is working.

Comment: Why do you think dropping the connection would cause an exception?

Comment: @James_D Cuz its used to work the same way as in Swings. I've quoted in OP, thats this project is based on swings, and em porting it to JavaFX from scratch.

Comment: @James_D I finally got it to be working. Thanks.